# calling runas.exe from inside windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, runas

I am trying to launch a console application from windows service (i am aware it is not advisable and is tricky but still). searching around, i found that it should be launched with a user context and sessions associated (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx). I also found a utility where we can launch processes in specific user context using RunAs.exe. my question is: can i launch the console application using RunAs.exe from inside the service and bypass the restriction to launch console application from windows services? background: the service is a java program converted into a windows service. the service itself doesn't create any windows but launches another process that creates a console window. Thanks!

Comment: Why not try and let us know about?  Question is more suitable for superuser (I guess)

Comment: sure, i will try and post the results. The problem is, even if it works, i will not be sure if there are specific cases, caveats associated! thanks for the tip, i will post it in the superuser also.

Comment: @Jayan When you recommend other sites, please tell users that their question can be migrated. Double-posting is not allowed. Thiru, please delete this question here when you post it somewhere else.